# getters not reactive in vuex

Tags: vuex, store, getter, reactive, vuedraggable

I have following `store` defined:

```
 state: () => ({
    infoPackCreationData: null,
    infoPackCreationTab: null,
  }),
getters: {
  infoPackImage(state: any) {
      return state.infoPackCreationTab && state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents
        ? state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents.filter((item: any) => item.type === "IMAGE")
        : [];
    }
},
mutations: {
  setImageData(state:any, infopackImageData: any) {
      state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents.filter((item: any) => {if(item.type === "IMAGE")
      item = infopackImageData
        console.log(item , 'this is items');
      return item})
    }
},
 actions: {
    setImageData(context: any, payload: any) {
      context.commit('setImageData', payload)
    }
}
```

and in my component I am using the `computed` to get the `imageList`:

```
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters("creationStore", ["infoPackImage"]),
      imageList: {
        get() {
          return this.infoPackImage ?? [];
        },
        set(value) {
         this.$store.dispatch('creationStore/setImageData', value);
        }
      }
    },
```

The problem is I want to edit a value of the `imageList` by `index` using draggable libarary,
but imageList does not act reactive and it just move the image and not showing the other image in the previous index:

```
  async imageChange(e) {
        this.loading = true
        let newIndex = e.moved.newIndex;
        let prevOrder = this.imageList[newIndex - 1]?.order ?? 0
        let nextOrder = this.imageList[newIndex + 1]?.order ?? 0
        const changeImageOrder = new InfopackImageService();
        try {
          return await changeImageOrder.putImageApi(this.$route.params.infopackId,
            this.$route.params.tabId,
            e.moved.element.id, {
              title: e.moved.element.title,
              infopackAssetRef: e.moved.element.infopackAssetRef,
              order: nextOrder,
              previousOrder: prevOrder,
            }).then((res) => {
            let image = {}
            let infopackAsset = e.moved.element.infopackAsset
            image = {...res, infopackAsset};
            Vue.set(this.imageList, newIndex , image)
            this.loading = false
            return this.imageList
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e, 'this is put error for tab change')
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.prototype.filter doesn't modify an array in-place, it returns a new array. So this mutation isn't ever changing any state:

```
mutations: {
  setImageData(state:any, infopackImageData: any) {
      state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents.filter((item: any) => {if(item.type === "IMAGE")
      item = infopackImageData
        console.log(item , 'this is items');
      return item})
    }
},
```

So, if you intend to change `state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents`, you'll need to assign the result of filter():

```
mutations: {
  setImageData(state:any, infopackImageData: any) {
      state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents = state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents.filter(...)
```

*However*, since `state.infoPackCreationTab` did not have an `infopackContents` property during initialization, it will not be reactive unless you use Vue.set() or just replace the whole `infoPackCreationTab` object with a new one (see: [Vuex on reactive mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules)):

```
mutations: {
  setImageData(state:any, infopackImageData: any) {
    state.infoPackCreationTab = {
      ...state.infoPackCreationTab,
      infopackContents: state.infoPackCreationTab.infopackContents.filter(...)
    };
```