# Problems with Vue.js 3 and Pinia Getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, draggable, pinia

I'm switching from Angular to Vue.js and trying to understand the architecture. I'm currently running into a fundamental problem and working with a lot of workarounds that I really only consider temporary solutions.

The main issue here is the collaboration between Vue.js 3 and Pinia. Pinia consists of the Store, Getters and Actions. Sometimes we have very nested objects in the Store and we only need certain parts of it. For that, it's perfect to create a getter, for example, to output only the parts of the object that I need.

But what if I want to change exactly those parts of the object from the template? My wish is that the data in the store changes as well. But since getters are readonly, this is not possible.

How would one proceed here?

Of course I would like to show you an example to underline my explanations with some practice.

```
export const useGeneralStore = defineStore('general', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      roles: [],
      currentRole: 'basic',
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getElementsForCurrentRole: (state) => {
      let role = state.roles.find((role) => {
        return role.value == state.currentRole;
      });

      if (role) {
        return role.data;
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {}
})
```

I am creating a store here with a very nested object `roles`. In the getter `getElementsForCurrentRole`, which I use in the template for a v-for, I only need certain elements.

To make it easier for you to understand, I'm also sending the template code here:

```
<template>
  <div class="element-container">
    <div v-for="cat of elementCategories" :key="cat">
      <h4>{{cat}}</h4>
      <draggable 
        v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole" 
        :group="cat"
        @end="save" 
        item-key="name">
        <template #item="{element}">
          <n-card v-if="element.category == cat" class="element" :class="element.name" :title="element.name" size="small" header-style="{titleFontSizeSmall: 8px}" hoverable>
            <n-switch v-model:value="element.active" @update:value="save(element)" size="small" />
          </n-card>
        </template>
      </draggable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { NCard, NSwitch, useMessage } from 'naive-ui';
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
  import { usePermissionsStore } from '@/stores/permissions';
  import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

  const permissionsStore = usePermissionsStore();
  const { getElementsForCurrentRole } = storeToRefs(permissionsStore);  

  const elementCategories = ['basic', 'professional'];
</script>
```

I loop through the `getElementsForCurrentRole` getter after using the `storeToRefs` function mentioned in the documentation to make the data reactive. My problem here is that the data is probably only partially reactive. For example, if I change the value of the `Switch` element, then the store updates successfully. This works. However, I don't seem to have access to the order of the array I'm looping. As soon as I change the order by drag and drop, I get the message: `Write operation failed: computed value is readonly`.

I don't understand this and I can't comprehend it.

As a workaround I currently calculate the old and the new index of the record in the array after dragging based on the event and update the store manually. But that can't be the purpose behind it. Have I fundamentally misunderstood something in the architecture? How would one approach such a case?

Comment: "Have I fundamentally misunderstood something in the architecture" - probably yes, a state isn't supposed to be directly mutated from the outside, this is the case for actions. Pinia is less restrictive than Vuex in this regard but the same concerns apply to it. Computeds (which Pinia getters are) are readonly, unless they are explicitly made writable . And you'd need to dispatch an action on write

Comment: Thank you very much, @Estus Flask. How could the getter in my example be made writable? Or is a completely different approach more advisable here? Before the project gets too big and I go down the wrong paths, I'd rather understand it better and get it right from the start.

Comment: Don't use storeToRefs but define a computed yourself. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed . A computed would look like imageList here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66441246/getters-not-reactive-in-vuex

Comment: Would writable getters be a clean solution? And: in the official Vue Store Pinia is there is currently no chance to create writable getters to achieve such simple things like the example above? Do I understand correctly? If yes: crazy!

Comment: Yes. It's simply `computed({ get: () => store.myValGetter, set: (v) => store.setMyVal(v)`, it can be used with v-model. The point here is that a way to get a value from a store and set it aren't necessarily symmetrical and not always be solved with simple assignment. Pinia is relatively thin wrapper around Vue reactivity, so there's no problem if Pinia itself doesn't provide it

Comment: And the `setMyVal(v)` would be an action in the store. Correct?

Comment: Yes. One of benefits is that all calls to setMyVal will be tracked in Pinia devtools

Comment: Just tested. Works wonderfully and makes sense. And if it's this clean, I'm really happy. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a getter. Getters are readonly propreties. To update value in any pinia store you must create an action.
And you are using a v-model which binds and writes when the value changes. It can therefore read with the getter but not write. In your case there are several possibilities. one of them is to make a computed property and an action. like this

```
actions: {
  updateRole(newRole) {
    this.currentRole = newRole
}
```

and the computed property in component:

```
const myComputed = computed({
  get: () => getElementsForCurrentRole.value,
  set: (val) => updateRole(val),
})
```